# Microsoft Editor's ￼ object replacement character

Tags: character-encoding, spell-checking, spacing, windows-11, character-replacement

I am using Microsoft Editor feature (Windows 11) a lot - I really depend on it, and I find all its features equally useful (Spelling Suggestions, Grammar Suggestions), but I find especially useful to me suggestions regarding spacing (this falls under Grammar Suggestions, and it gets blue underline emphasis; Grammar Suggestions further offers suggestions on punctuations, and so on). The problem is that sometimes, not always, suggestion comes with this small icon-like box-like " ￼ " *object replacement character*. My first thought was that its appearance depends on websites' character code, font, something like that - for instance, it did not appear here while I was writing this post but appears in Wikipedia which is my hobby, and many other websites.

What can be done, if anything, to stop that annoying little box when I want to apply fix on spacing (it is usually excess of space between word and punctuation, or suggestion to add or remove unnecessary punctuation). I hope this post doesn't look convoluted and too confusing, so thanks in advance to anyone able to offer helping hand in form of explanation and/or advice.